# How to identify javascript cross domain policy error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am looking for a method that helps quickly identify if a js form error is related to [cross domain policy mecanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If possible this method needs to be done from remote connection, as I do not have access to production server and everything is working fine in local sandbox and staging server.  The issue only comes up on production server.

This occurs on a drupal webform that has a file upload field, used for an image upload. Ie8 and Ie9 fail to upload, the throbber runs indefinetely and a js ajax message is returned and interpreted as a downloable file. The file contains the ajax response.

I am by no means a js guru and this one has me stumped. How would one identify / troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: In ff open firebug (if you have, f12; if not... install it). If some request is blocked (do cross domain policy fault) in the console you should get an error like "access restricted bla bla" or something like that.